# Поиск последовательности значений в столбце DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, оптимизация, numpy

В DataFrame содержаться упорядоченные даннные с путем следования маршрутов:

```
index  номер_автобуса номер_остановки
    1              73       Алтуфьево
    2              73        Бибирево
    3              73        Отрадное
    4              80        Бибирево
    5              80        Отрадное
    6              90        Отрадное
    7              90        Бибирево
```

Также есть некий маршрут пользователя.

Задача в том, чтобы отобрать все сонаправленые некоему перечню остановок отрезки маршрутов. Например, для `[Алтуфьево, Бибирево, Отрадное]` подходят отрезки маршрута `73` и `80`.

Как это сделать не прибегая ко множеству вложенных циклов?

Comment: А датафрейм-то где?

Comment: В таблице. Она не отображается? Первый мой вопрос. Извиняюсь если что не так.

Comment: [что делать с ответами на вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @Smoooky, [данный ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134881/211923) вам не помог?

Comment: С чего Вы это взяли?

Comment: @Smoooky Вы же не написали комментарий, почему вам предложенное решение не подошло и как его можно улучшить. Используйте @_ник, чтобы приходили уведмления.

Comment: @0xdb Спасибо за комментарий. Это мой первый вопрос на этой платформе, поэтому не сильно знаком с правилами сообщества.

Comment: @Smoooky Хорошо, знакомтесь, вам дали ссылку вверху. Если вам дали ответ, то тут две возможности: 1) ответ не помог, то написать под ответом комментарий с указанием, почему не помог 2) если помог, то отметить как принятый (галочка слева от ответа). Как сделаете, то напишите мне короткий комментарий, чтобы я смог отозвать минус.

Comment: @0xdb уже написал коммент к ответу. Еще раз спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()
# искомый маршрут в виде списка
srch_route = "Алтуфьево Бибирево Отрадное".split()
# обучаем LabelEncoder на всех названиях остановок
le.fit(df["номер_остановки"].tolist() + srch_route)
# создаем столбец с закодированным названием остановки    
df["route"] = le.transform(df["номер_остановки"])
# кодируем искомый маршрут
route_points = list(map(str, le.transform(srch_route)))
# создаем закодированные пути поиска
srch_paths = []
for ii in range(len(route_points)-1):
    srch_paths.append("~".join(route_points[ii:]))
srch_pat = "|".join(srch_paths)
# создаем вспомогательный фрейм с закодированными маршрутами автобусов
d = df.groupby("номер_автобуса")["route"].apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.cat(sep="~")).reset_index()
# ищем подходящие номера автобусов
res = d.loc[d["route"].str.contains(srch_pat, regex=True), "номер_автобуса"]
```

---

результат:

```
In [61]: res
Out[61]:
0    73
1    80
Name: номер_автобуса, dtype: int64
```

---

вспомогательный фрейм:

```
In [65]: d
Out[65]:
   номер_автобуса  route
0              73  0~1~2
1              80    1~2
2              90    2~1
```

RegEx для поиска маршрута пользователя с закодированными остановками:

```
In [66]: srch_pat
Out[66]: '0~1~2|1~2'
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Прошу Вас ответить на еще несколько вопросов. Насколько LabelEncoder ускоряет алкоритм? Зачем кодировать остановки? Я же могу просто сделать вспомогательный фрейм с остановками в том же виде в, котором они есть и с помощью регулярных выражений так же его отработать?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, @MaxU. Прошу Вас ответить на еще несколько вопросов. Насколько LabelEncoder ускоряет алкоритм? Зачем кодировать остановки? Я же могу просто сделать вспомогательный фрейм с остановками в том же виде, в, котором они есть и с помощью регулярных выражений так же его отработать?
Так же данный алгоритм упускает некоторые маршруты, которые будут являться сонаправленными. Например в датафрейме может быть маршрут Алтуфьево - Бибирево. И данный алгоритм его не найдет.

Comment: так же данный алгоритм не найдет маршрут Алтуфьево - Отрадное.  Хотя он тоже является сонаправленным.